# C# xUnit Test error - The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit.net

I have implemented a unit test on my ASP.NET Core MVC project using xUnit.  When I try to run the test, it gave me an error as below:

> The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: Status status"

Below is my code:

IStatusService:

```
public interface IStatusService
{
    Task<StatusIndexViewModel> GetStatusAsync();
  
}
```

StatusService:

```
public class StatusService : IStatusService
{
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public StatusService(DbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<StatusIndexViewModel> GetStatusAsync()
    {
        var model = await dbContext
           .Status.AsNoTracking()
           .ProjectTo<StatusViewModel>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
           .ToListAsync();

        var vm = new StatusIndexViewModel
        {
            Statuses = model
        };

        return vm;
    }
   
}
```

Here is the Controller:

```
public class StatusController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStatusService statusService;

    public StatusController(IStatusService statusService)
    {
        this.statusService = statusService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = await statusService.GetStatusAsync();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Below is my unit test class:

```
public class StatusUnitTest
{
    StatusController StatusControllerTest;
    private Mock<IStatusService> statusService;
    private List<Status> statuses;
    private Status status;

    public StatusUnitTest(Status status)
    {
        this.status = status;
        statusService = new Mock<IStatusService>();
        statusService.Setup(p => 
        p.GetStatusAsync()).ReturnsAsync(status);
        StatusControllerTest = new StatusController(statusService.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetStatusByIdNo()
    {
        var result = await StatusControllerTest.Index();
        var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<Status>> 
       (viewResult.ViewData.Model);            
    }
}
```

May I know what mistake I made?  How I can test the controller and the service layer?  Please give me a guide.

Comment: If you want to inject status through the constructor of your xunit test, you have to implement `IClassFixture<Status>` in your test class. [source](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context)

Comment: Just a suggestion: I think you shouldn't be worry testing the controller or the API layer. In a well laid out project API layer is just like a traffic controller where you should have any logic there. So it would be better if you place all your business logic in one layer and cover that layer with as much unit tests. In this case write unit test for StatusService instead the StatusController.